# Burninate the costs tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I'm thinking we could do without [costs](/questions/tagged/costs), I'm an open source fan and it doesn't fit in with my ideology...

[image: Trogdor-Signal]

Joking aside it looks to be pretty useless; only 16 questions currently use it, a couple of which have been closed, a couple more probably need to be closed. The questions worth saving would probably be better tagged with something like [optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization) or [performance](/questions/tagged/performance).

So...

To burn, or not to burn, that is the question—
Whether 'tis Nobler in the mind to suffer
The tags and questions of outrageous Users,
Or to take Arms against a Sea of troubles,
And by opposing end them?

Comment: [discount](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discount) could go the way of the flames too.

Comment: What about [tag:cost]?

Comment: @Tshepang Nice find, I'll take a closer look when I have some time to kill.

Comment: [cost] and [costs] are now gone