# tag: markdown sometimes links to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, tags, markdown

*Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222148/202832).*

If I use [sometag](/questions/tagged/sometag) (`[tag:sometag]`) here, it goes to "sometag" on Meta Stack Exchange. **Good.**

But in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222148/202832), the same markdown links to Stack Overflow!

And to make this even stranger, on [the revisions page for that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/222148/revisions), the same tags link to Meta Stack Exchange!

### What is going on?

Comment: That's because the html is rendered on POST and then stored in the cache/DB, to update it, you need to edit the post.

Comment: The parsing is made when you submit the post. Only when editing the body it will take effect, I've now done a trivial edit and it's all good. Worth to mention, retag is not a real edit hence it wasn't re-parsed. :)

Comment: @m0sa what does it have to do with migrated questions? It's about the MSO/MSE split, not about migration.

Comment: ah I misread that it was migrated (vs meta split)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[tag:name]` pointed to Stack Overflow (correctly) when the post was written on Meta Stack *Overflow*.

It hasn't been edited since the transition to Meta Stack *Exchange*, so the cached post body still reflects the original state. The revision history always rerenders the post body from Markdown, which is why there is a discrepancy.